# Problem running project from s4sdk archtypes with artifact id: scp-cf-spring

Tags: s4sdk

I'm getting issues in running hello world project when I created it from below command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-spring -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST
```

The project gets created fine but when I'm running the application I get an error in creating beans, the error looks something like this:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheMonitor': Cannot create
>   inner bean '(inner bean)#630d4350' of type
>   [com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheMonitor] while setting
>   bean property 'listener'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error
>   loading class [com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheMonitor] for
>   bean with name '(inner bean)#630d4350' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/Users/setup/.m2/repository/com/sap/cloud/s4hana/cloudplatform/caching/2.4.2-SNAPSHOT/caching-2.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/cache/CacheMonitor.class]:
>   problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/monitoring/JmxMonitor . . .
>
> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error
>   loading class [com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.cache.CacheMonitor] for
>   bean with name '(inner bean)#630d4350' defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/Users/setup/.m2/repository/com/sap/cloud/s4hana/cloudplatform/caching/2.4.2-SNAPSHOT/caching-2.4.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/cache/CacheMonitor.class]:
>   problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sap/cloud/sdk/cloudplatform/monitoring/JmxMonitor . . .
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sap.cloud.sdk.cloudplatform.monitoring.JmxMonitor

Please let me know if I should furnish more details.

Comment: Can provide some more details on what you have done? If I run your command the project is generated just fine (as you have written) and runs locally as well as on CloudFoundry without a problem. A first glance at the stacktrace, however, leads me to the assumption, that you are missing the `com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:core` dependency on your classpath. Can you verify that via `mvn dependency:tree`?

Comment: @ChristophSchubert Result of my dependency tree contains: com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:core-scp-cf:jar:2.4.2-SNAPSHOT:compile, shouldn't this be sufficient ?  The -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST generated my project with 2.4.2-SNAPSHOT

Comment: I generated project with version: 2.3.1, it is working fine now.: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-spring -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.1,   Seems there is some problem with snapshots

Comment: The SNAPSHOT versions are our current develop builds, so they can be somewhat unstable. However, I would like to understand your issue to prevent it from finding its way into the 2.4.2 release. Can you please add the output of the command `mvn dependency:tree -pl application -Dincludes=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:core` to your question?

Comment: Result:  Scanning for projects...
[INFO] Building mkt-agency-app - Application 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ mkt-agency-app-application ---
[INFO] com.sap.cec.mkt:mkt-agency-app-application:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.frameworks:cxf:jar:2.4.2-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO]    \- com.sap.cloud.s4hana.cloudplatform:core:jar:2.4.2-SNAPSHOT:compile

Comment: Okay, so the dependency is on your classpath. Then I have no further idea, what the actual problem is. In combination with your other question I would just assume some issue in your maven cache. To mark this question as "answered" can you please provide an answer containing your fix/downgrade to the actual releases version?

Comment: Sure, the fix is:  I generated project with version: 2.3.1, it is working fine now.: mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-spring -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.1

Comment: Okay, little misunderstanding here: I meant that you provide this as a real answer to your own question above so that you can accept it and this question is officially flagged as answered. That way you will also get some Stackoverflow reputation :-)

Answer (score 1):

The fix is: I generated project with version: 2.3.1, it is working fine now.:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-spring -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.1
```